# Calling views from subclasses

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, delegates, subview

I have an iPhone app primarily made of two views, let's call them `fullScreen` and `cardViews` (the `cardViews` are presented as subViews of the full screen views). I've handled all of the animations in presenting the card Views by having a `masterCardViewClass` and a `masterFullScreenViewClass`. All specific cardViews are subclasses of the masterCardView, all specific fullScreenViews are subclasses of the masterFullScreenView.

I present a cardView with a method from the `masterFullScreenViewClass`. I dismiss the cardView with a delegate method from the masterCardView. However, I'm having a problem calling a method to present a cardView from another cardView. All cardView presenting methods are contained in the masterFullScreenViewController class.

How do I access these methods without copying a pasting them locally where I need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is by using protocols.

In a nutshell, your `masterCardView class` would implement a protocol method that presents a `cardView` (for the sake of simplicity, let's say that you invoke cardViews with a certain index):

**masterCardView.h:**

```
@protocol CardPresenterDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)presentCardViewWithIndex:(int)index;

@end

@interface MasterCardView:UIViewController <CardPresenterDelegate>
...
```

**masterCardView.m:**

```
- (void)presentCardViewWithIndex:(int)index
{
// Code for presenting a cardView
}
```

You would also need to create a delegate (weak) property in your cardView:

**cardView.h**

```
@property (weak) id<CardPresenterDelegate> cardPresenterDelegate;
```

And then by accessing that property in your cardView, you can tell the masterCardView to do something for you:

**cardView.m**

```
[self.cardPresenterDelegate presentCardViewWithIndex:5];
```

Oh, and, don't forget to set the delegate property on your cardViews when creating them in your masterCardView:

back in **masterCardView.m:**

```
cardView.cardPresenterDelegate = self;
```